# sudo: /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh: command not found

Tags: kubuntu, libraries

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-restricted-extras
```

seems to run fine

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

gives:

```
sudo: /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh: command not found
```

have run 
    sudo apt-get update
several times

how to fix? how to get libdvdread4 to install?

```
michaeleric@michaeleric-Inspiron-1750:~$ sudo apt-get install libdvdread4  
[sudo] password for michaeleric:   
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done  
libdvdread4 is already the newest version (5.0.3-1).  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
michaeleric@michaeleric-Inspiron-1750:~$ sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh  
sudo: /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh: command not found  
michaeleric@michaeleric-Inspiron-1750:~$
```

==========================================

```
sudo apt install libdvdcss2 libdvdread4 libdvdnav4 ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

seems to install

```
michaeleric@michaeleric-Inspiron-1750:~$ sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.shsudo: /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh: command not found
```

===========================================

Comment: does not seem to. say it is newest, but command not found

Comment: Install the apps like in the linked answer.  You are probably missing one of the other apps needed to play.

Comment: Have you tried reading a disc since you installed all this stuff?  I don't think there is a need to run `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`.  I never had to run that.

Comment: yep. several. that is why i did a search for vlc not playing movies, and came back to this

Comment: `libdvdcss2` installs the `css` needed to play movies.  There is no longer the `/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` so you will not be able to run that as it is not required any longer.  In the linked answer the question that was asked because it would not work.  I helped them and it worked fine.  If you have to, remove all those applications and start again.

Answer (score 7):

Since Ubuntu 16.04 you don't need to run `/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` but install the package `libdvd-pkg` to get `libdvdcss2`